# Ordering options in ng-options with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

The select element shown below is populated with Angular 1.47 (code also shown).  I'd prefer that the current value -45 bp - be at the top of the list, not the bottom.  How can I accomplish this?

[image: My dropdown]

```
  <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header edit-modal" style="border-style: solid; border-width: 1px;">
        <button type="button" class="close" ng-click="close()" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
        <div>Test Dialog </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form class="form-horizontal ng-pristine ng-valid" role="form">
             <div class="row edit-modal">
                <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
                <div class="col-sm-5 text-left label-no-padding">Option  1</div>
                <div class="col-sm-5">
                 <select style="width:150px" ng-model="Option1" ng-options="Option1 as Option1.label for Option1 in dropdown.Option1 | orderBy:'orderId'" class="ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched"></select>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
            </div>  
            <div class="row edit-modal">
                <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
                <div class="col-sm-5 text-left label-no-padding">Option 2</div>
                <div class="col-sm-5">
                 <select style="width:150px" ng-model="Option2" ng-options="Option2 as Option2.label for Option2 in dropdownValueMap.Option2| orderBy:'orderId'" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid"></select>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
            </div>  
            <div class="row edit-modal">
                <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
                <div class="col-sm-5 text-left label-no-padding">Option 3</div>
                <div class="col-sm-5">
                <select style="width:150px" ng-model="Option3" ng-options="Option3 as Option3.label for Option3 in dropdown.Option3 | orderBy:'orderId'" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid"></select>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
            </div>  
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" ng-click="closeSave()" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">OK</button>
        <button type="button" ng-click="close()" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: it seems you want to manually sort the array according to some rule rather than using orderBy. You would need to create a custom filter which does orderBy but then moves the 45 to the beginning of the list

Comment: sorting?  I'm ok with the order.  I just want 45 bp to be at the top & the items below that (46 bp, 47 bp etc) to show below it..  This is not a huge deal, it just seems like it should be possible

Comment: So do you want to reverse the order? Actually can you provide an example of how you want the data to show?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I saw that you are using `orderBy` filter.

- If you use `orderBy:'orderId'`, order is increasing (27, 28, 29, 30).
- If you use `orderBy:'-orderId'`, order is descending (30, 29, 28, 27).

Take a look to: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy

Hope I helped :)